# Feed my AppleTv with media from my Ubuntu desktop PC

Tags: itunes, ipad

I'm about to buy an AppleTv and I'm wondering if it is possible to access the media that are hosted on my ubuntu PC.

At home, I have:

- A Ubuntu PC with all my media on it
- A Windows Laptop (not always available/running) that I'm using to configure my IPad2 (and soon, my AppleTv)
- An IPad2

For what I understand:

- AppleTv can access the media via ITunes if it is opened on my Windows laptop.
- I can stream media from my IPad2 to the AppleTv (in the case ITunes is not available)

Is it possible for me to setup my Ubuntu PC to send media via Airplay to the AppleTv?

---

**EDIT** : If it is not possible via airplay, any other suggestion are welcomed.

---

**EDIT2** : What about intalling XBMC or thin Plex client on a jailbroken Apple TV (2nd or 3rd gen)?

Thanks

Comment: it's probably not possible via airplay since that's a closed protocol.

Comment: @Alvar i might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that airplay is an open standard. Also, you could do something with firefly/DAAP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_Media_Server

Comment: @jrg I was wrong, look a bit down and you will see that the key is released so third-party software can now be developed. I just assumed it was a closed protocol since Apple made it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would perhaps be to run iTunes on the Ubuntu PC through Wine. From what I've heard, the syncing part doesn't work, but the airplay features does.

Second option is using Ubuntu One, if you only want to play audio as per : [The Ubuntu One Blog](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2010/12/06/yet-another-way-to-enjoy-ubuntu-one-music-streaming-the-home-entertainment-experience/)

Third solution would be to install a media server on the Ubuntu PC as [this guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Creating-a-Home-Media-Streaming-Center-with-Ubuntu/?ALLSTEPS#step1) dictates.

Disclaimer: Haven't got an Apple TV or even a Mac myself, so I haven't tested any of the proposed solutions. =)

Happy testing!

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search provided this [link](http://www.ipadforums.net/airplay/25028-howto-stream-videos-apple-tv-2-using-ipad-under-ubuntu.html) that includes a few scripts and step by step documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a easy but $$$ way, check out the AirPlayer http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airplayer/id369713694?mt=8

It is $4.99 though but you wont have to use itunes to stream and is confirmed to work with other media serving software like PS3 Media Server or Serviio (Installs are easy with these 2)

Comment: this is windows / mac, not linux

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `mt-daapd` package which is an iTunes compatible DAAP server.

> mt-daapd, now known as the Firefly Media Server, is a DAAP (Digital
>   Audio  Access Protocol) server that works with most POSIX-compatible
>   operating  systems. It allows you to share your music collection over
>   the local network  using the DAAP protocol also used by Apple's
>   iTunes.

More information on how to use it and links to the Launchpad page can be [found here](http://%20mt-daapd,%20now%20known%20as%20the%20Firefly%20Media%20Server,%20is%20a%20DAAP%20%28Digital%20Audio%20%20Access%20Protocol%29%20server%20that%20works%20with%20most%20POSIX-compatible%20operating%20%20systems.%20It%20allows%20you%20to%20share%20your%20music%20collection%20over%20the%20local%20network%20%20using%20the%20DAAP%20protocol%20also%20used%20by%20Apple%27s%20iTunes.).
There is an example available on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1493324) on how to set it up as well